# how we can set false value for CFString in swift, for kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying

Tags: swift

I am trying to set a true or false value for "kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying" which takes CFString value and I already tried: "false", "False", "no", "No", "kCFBooleanFalse" but I could not be successful, So how I can give false value for a CFString which used for "kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying"

PS: I am using password for pdf, and it works well.

My code:

```
let pdfFormat = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
let metaData = [
                kCGPDFContextTitle: "Hello, World!",
                kCGPDFContextAuthor: "Omid",
                kCGPDFContextCreator: "PDF Creator",
                kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword: "123",
                kCGPDFContextUserPassword: "123",
                kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying: "false"
            ]
pdfFormat.documentInfo = metaData as [String: Any]
let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: dimensionsOfDocument, format: pdfFormat)

try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: filename) { context in . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it `0 as NSNumber` for `false` or `1 as NSNumber` for `true`. You can also set it to `false as CFBoolean` or `true as CFBoolean`. Note that this is done automatically for you under the hood.

> CFBoolean objects are used to wrap boolean values for use in Core Foundation property lists and collection types.

You can simply set it to false. The issue there is that when you save your PDF using `writePDF(to:)` this info (don't ask me why) is not persisted. You can work around this issue using PDFDocument method write `write(to:, withOptions:)` and set your `kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying` value to `false` there:

```
import PDFKit
let pdfFormat = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
let metaData: [CFString : Any] = [
                kCGPDFContextTitle: "Hello, World!",
                kCGPDFContextAuthor: "Omid",
                kCGPDFContextCreator: "PDF Creator"]
pdfFormat.documentInfo = metaData as [String: Any]
let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8.5 * 72.0, height: 11 * 72.0)
let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: pdfFormat)
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let data = pdfRenderer.pdfData { (context) in
        context.beginPage()
        let textFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60, weight: .regular)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        let string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, .font: textFont])
        let textSize = attributedText.boundingRect(with: bounds.size, options: [.usesFontLeading, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], context: nil)
        attributedText.draw(in: .init(x: 10, y: 10, width: bounds.width - 20, height: textSize.height))
}
let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.pdf")
try data.write(to: fileURL)
let pdf = PDFDocument(url: fileURL)!
let pdfProtectedURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("protected.pdf")
pdf.write(to: pdfProtectedURL, withOptions: [
            kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying as PDFDocumentWriteOption: false,
            kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting as PDFDocumentWriteOption: false,
            kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword as PDFDocumentWriteOption: "12345678",
            kCGPDFContextUserPassword as PDFDocumentWriteOption: "123"])
```

Comment: You are setting a string not a NSNumber. You need to define your dictionary as `[String: Any]`

Comment: I modified my codes to yours, still selectable after creating. :-(

Comment: **Whether the document allows copying when unlocked with the user password. The value of this key must be a CFBoolean object. The default value of this key is true.** there is nothing to do with allowing selection

Comment: So let me ask you this, I am trying to make texts inside of pdf un-selectable! almost like a Image. I am thinking we can make a selectable text of pdf un-selectable with using of kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, is it right?

Comment: As I already mentioned it will avoid copying the text. You can't disable selecting the text in your PDF. It depends on the software you are using, not on the PDF itself. If you would like to avoid text selection in PDFView you can override canPerformAction method and return false to select action. The only way to avoid selection in the PDF itself is to convert your text to image.

Comment: thanks for explain, even with all you said and even with your code I am able to copying in false mode. why it is possible? I run your code and build my pdf, then I unlock the pdf and start selecting some text inside pdf, copy selected text and I can paste the selection. According your cods and explain it should not be possible.

Comment: I don't know what is false mode

Comment: false mode: This: kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying as String: false as CFBoolean

Comment: Well the documentation says it **"Whether the document allows copying when unlocked with the user password"** I haven't tested so I can't really tell why it doesn't work as it should. I answered your question about how to set the value for that key. I'm pretty sure that it is correct.

Comment: @Omid check my last edit. It worked for me. You need to write your pdf with options

Comment: thanks, it works for me also. As you know better than me, there is 2 way to build PDF, 1- with UIGraphicsPDFRendered, 2- with PDFKit, I did not expected that the issue could be our method! why it is working with PDFKit and not working with UIGraphicsPDFRendered? I think UIGraphicsPDFRendered is the basic way and more closer to CPU rather than PDFKit. But I can be also wrong

Comment: @Omid I don't know. There is no `writePDF` with options

Comment: I read an Article, working with PDF is not easy and there is some issues with it, but it was nice that you gave the write answer the better way is (.write) and Not (.pdfData) I was Very interested to ImageContext way and not touching PDFKit, but sometimes like the issue we spoke we have to choose PDFKit.

Comment: @Omid actually when creating your dictionary you can simply set the value to false. check my last edit